# Using define_method to define global methods outside of a module

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I'd like to write this:

```
[:p, :h1, :h3].each do |tag|
  define_method(tag) { |text| "<#{tag}>#{text}</#{tag}>" }
end
```

It's just some simple methods to wrap text in HTML tags.  I want to be able to use these methods in the rest of the script.  Unfortunately the `define_method` method seems to only work inside of a module.  But if I did this inside a module, I wouldn't be able to cleanly write `p "This is a paragraph."`, it'd be something like `HTML::p "This is a paragraph."` which would be pretty terrible.

So how do I define methods like this globally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know your whole situation, but you probably don't really want to be defining global methods. If you don't want to type the `HTML::` then add an `include HTML` statement at the beginning of your code.

Comment: this seemed hacky at first but I guess it's pretty clean and it works perfectly.  Thankyou!

Answer (score 5):

If you really need to do it:

```
[:p, :h1, :h3].each do |tag|
    Object.send(:define_method, tag) { |text| "<#{tag}>#{text}</#{tag}>" }
end
```

Answer (score 2):

One hack would be to create the method inside Object, which would then be global method you desire:

```
class Object
  def create_method(name, &block)
    self.class.send(:define_method, name, &block)
  end
end

tag = 'p'
a = Object.new
a.create_method(tag.intern) {|v| puts "<#{tag}>#{v}</#{tag}>"}

send(tag.intern, 'content') # => <p>content</p>
```

Comment: This code does not define 'global' methods, it only defines methods on the class of the receiver. In this example `a` is an instance of Object so the methods would be 'global' but in general this is not true with your code.

Comment: This of course only works with class Object ... within which I added the method create_method. Just to be clear, this is not a good style , from my personal feeling, but just one way to meet the original question's intension.